# Non resized images have content length 0 and content type missing

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

I have a site that is using the ImageResizer. But not all images use the resizer, we have some images which are not resized. And these seem to be having a content-length of 0 and also the content type is missing in the response headers. We are using AzureReader2 along with DiskCache plugin. Is there any setting or a tweak I am missing. This is a super critical task for me, any feedback is greatly appreciated.

For example:

Does not work:

```
https://www.example.com/globalassets/home-page/23491_2_2.jpg
```

This works fine:

```
https://www.example.com/globalassets/home-page/23491_2_2.jpg?height=1000&width=1000
```

Below is what I have in my web.config

```
<resizer>
<Clientcache minutes="720" />
<plugins>
<add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/azure" connectionString="EPiServerAzureBlobs"/>
<add name="EPiServerBlobReaderPlugin" />
<add name="DiskCache" />
</plugins>
<licenses>
<license>

</license>
</licenses>
</resizer>
```

Answer (score 0):

EPI server overrides the handling of static files in a way that sometimes doesn't work well.

You may try `<add name="AzureReader2" vpp="true" cacheUnmodifiedFiles="true" prefix="~/azure" connectionString="EPiServerAzureBlobs"/>`

Sometimes this forces the request to be handled properly.

https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/azurereader2